# sql query to get two differnt values of same columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rdbms, codeigniter-3

I am making an activity log for my website and to show the logs that user 1 followed user 2, I have their ids in my `activity_log` table. Now I want to retrieve their names from `user_login` table.

For example `user_id=3;friend_id=6;`. I want their username so that in activity log I can print "`$user followed $friend`". So I want to know about the query so that I can retrieve usernames using two variables, suppose variables are `$finalres1=3;$finalres2=6;` How do I fetch their usernames from table `user_login` with a single query

```
foreach($results as $res=>$finalres){
    $finalres1=$finalres['user_id'];
    $finalres2=$finalres['friend_id'];

    $this->db->select('username');
    $this->db->from('user_login');
    $this->db->where('id',$finalres1);

    $query=$this->db->get();
    $result3=$query->result_array();
```

this query fetches me the username of user 1 but I need username of both the user and friend in single array.so in the view I can write them easily.

Comment: Just add `$this->db->or_where('id',$finalres2);` into your query to get both username!!

Comment: thank you so much brother,it works fine.

Comment: @Saty add as answer

Answer (score 0):

> add that

```
$this->db->or_where('id',$finalres2)
```

Comment: @AbdullaNilam No

Comment: i have a problem, <?foreach ($results as $result=>$res)
         {
         echo $res['username'];};;;;;;;;;;;;Array ( [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => Jagan ) [1] => Array ( [username] => rahulchut ) ) both have same index 'username'how cani access them seprately??my concept of arrays are a little weak.

Answer (score 0):

> add that
>    $this->db->select('username as username1');
>       $this->db->from('user_login');
>       $this->db->where('id',$finalres1);